# RethinkDB host on Synology NAS

Tags: rethinkdb, synology

How can i install RethinkDB on a Synology NAS?

Synology 's OS has no apt-get.

https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/

greets
philipp

Answer (score 0):

You can [build](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/build/) it yourself from [source](https://download.rethinkdb.com/dist/rethinkdb-2.2.1.tgz).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use static linked build to run an app on Synology NAS. For instance, we can take the package of Alpine Linux, since it is static link build. Someone did some work of that: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4437

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'll post an updated answer. Nowadays, most Synology NAS devices can run software using Docker.

As per RethinkDB documentation, you can find an official image of RethinkDB on the Docker Hub.

You can follow this guide to install RethinkDB on your Synology NAS: https://tutorialsight.com/how-to-install-rethinkdb-on-your-synology-nas/